# How to get devise user email in UserMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, actionmailer

I want to send Thank You emails to users who have just registered, I think I have got everything right but somehow not able to get registered user's email ID in user_mailer.rb. I am using devise and using current_user.email or @current_user.email is giving error. This is my code

```
#/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb
def welcome (current_user)
  mail(
    :from => "myid@gmail.com",
    :to => current_user.email,
    :subject => "Thank you for signing"
  )
end
```

#/app/controllers/registration_controller.rb

```
def create
  build_resource

  if resource.valid?
    begin
      resource.transaction do
        resource.save!
      end
    UserMailer.welcome(@current_user).deliver
  end
end
```

error I am getting

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
```

**EDIT** - alright I am finally able to solve it, in controller I was using UserMailer.welcome(@current_user).deliver instead of UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver, now it is working, thanks for everyone who helped

Comment: Can you add the complete code of `registrations_controller#create` ?

Comment: your `current_user` is nil that means your are not logged in so `current_user.email` should throw error

Comment: @Neo - I have added the complete code

Comment: @Rajarshi - yes it certainly looks so,I have added the complete code, I am certainly saving the resource before using current_user.email though

Comment: hmm. I got the actual error right?:)..Thanks

Comment: @Rajarshi - well I am assuming that is the error but I don't know the solution i.e. how to fix it ?

Comment: just add a condition over there #/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb unless current_user.nil? else ...Hope you got it

Comment: Also in controller `UserMailer.welcome(resource).deliver`

Comment: @Rajarshi - Hi, I am unsure about the syntax due to formatting of SO, can you put it on jsfiddle or pastebin ? thanks

Comment: https://gist.github.com/rajcybage/6210925

Comment: @Rajarshi - alright I tested it, the email is certainly NIL since I am getting email put at else section https://gist.github.com/rajcybage/6210925, how can I fix this so it takes current_user.email ?

Comment: @Rajarshi - I am finally able to solve it, in controller I was using UserMailer.welcome(@current_user).deliver instead of UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver, now it is working, thanks for your help, really appreciate it

Comment: @iCyborg can you please vote me up on my post

Answer (score 2):

Use "resource" method to get current user if you overwrite devise controller:

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)

  if resource.save
    UserMailer.welcome(resource).deliver
    # some other actions...
  end
end
```

Also, may be you should place email sending code on model callbacks instead of controller?

Comment: I have added the complete controller code, should I put UserMailer.welcome(@current_user).deliver before resource.save ?

Comment: alright I put that "unless current_user.nil?...else..." code put above in comments https://gist.github.com/rajcybage/6210925, the email is certainly NIL since I am getting email listed at else section , how can I fix this so it takes current_user.email ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_up(:user, @user)
    UserMailer.welcome(@user).deliver
  else
    clean_up_passwords @user
  end
```

Comment: I am using devise and have created registations_controller.rb file I don't think I have to create user object again